# ADODB.RecordSet.MoveNext going up by 2

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb, recordset

I am importing a CSV into ACCESS using ADODB recordset. I am trying to iterate through the recordset to get data I need, but when I use the .MoveNext method it goes up 2 instead of one. By that I mean AbsolutePosition counts by 2s (1,3,5..) and I hit the EOF when the rowcounter I am using hits exactly half of the total number of records

```
Public Function ConnectToCSV(filePath As String, fileName As String)
Dim connString As String
Dim connection As ADODB.connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.recordSet
Dim currentRow As Long
dim readArray() as Variant

Set connection = New ADODB.connection
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & filePath & fileName & _
  ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';"

connection.Open connString

RS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & fileName, connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

currentRow = 0
RS.MoveLast
RS.MoveFirst

While Not RS.EOF
    readArray = RS.GetRows(1)
    RS.MoveNext
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you calling `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst` before entering the loop?

Comment: @Dai IIRC, it's a bug with the ADODB.Recordsets. Usually do this to get an accurate RecordCount.

Comment: Also, please show the actual code inside your `While` loop - it's possible you're seeing side-effects.

Comment: Can you replicate this with a contrived file that follows the same format? I wonder if it is how the file is formatted.

Comment: @Dai I added what I am actually doing - for now putting the row into an array using GetRows

Comment: @RyanWildry The file is a pretty basic semi-colon delimited CSV. Could the carriage returns in the file somehow be causing this? The thing is the RecordCount seems correct - matches the number of rows in the file. It's just that I am skipping ahead too fast

Comment: I would try a different recordset type i.e. not adOpenStatic.  I'm not sure how you are able to MoveLast and then MoveFirst using an adOpenStatic recordset type.

Answer (score 1):

The .GetRows(1) method I was using was already moving to the next record after retrieving the current record. By using the .MoveNext as well it was causing it to jump by 2 each loop.

I removed the .MoveNext and it appears to be working properly (jumping by 1)

Comment: You would get the same result by putting MoveNext back and removing currentRow = currentRow + 1.